# Development of the figurative meaning of derivare

Tags: classical-latin, etymology, nuance

If I understand correctly, [*derivare*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=derivo&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) means literally "to lead water from a river" (from [*rivus*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=rivus&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059)).
L&S gives examples of this literal meaning, but it also lists figurative uses.
Only the figurative sense remains in many loaned versions of the word, like the English "derive" — or at least I have never seen it mean anything water-related.

Do we know how this figurative meaning came about?
Was there a first author that introduced this sense?
What were the first abstract or generalized uses cases like?
Or was this meaning always there?
L&S gives examples, but it does not say if it was first introduced by someone (Cicero?).

I most interested in figurative meanings closer to the English "derive" than "divert", but any understanding of the development of figurative meanings of this word would be great.

Some mathematicians have asked me about the Latin meaning of (the word behind) "derive", but I have not been able to give a convincing answer that bridges the gap between "taking water" and "deriving".

Comment: Note that most of the figurative uses actually are closer to English "divert" than "derive."

Comment: @brianpck Good point! I added a little clarification to the question.

Comment: We'll never know who was the first to make it figurative, because there is always the possibility that some lost work did it first. Only a tiny fraction of ancient works survive, many of them by top tier authors, so it's not a stretch to think any given metaphor has a longer history than is evident.